# nodejs - How to add image data from file into canvas

Tags: image, node.js, canvas, html5-canvas

The following code is supposed to read an image file and then add the file data into a canvas with the help of the Canvas module.

When I run this code I receive the error message **Image is not defined**. Is the image object that I'm trying to initialise from a module that I simply import?

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs'), 
Canvas = require('canvas');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        img = new Image();
        img.src = data;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);

        res.write('<html><body>');
        res.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
        res.write('</body></html>');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I apologize if I'm wrong here, but it looks like you've found this code somewhere and tried to use it without actually understanding what's happening under the covers. Even if you were to fix the **Image is not defined** error, there are many others.

I have the fixed code at the end of this post, but I'd recommend thinking more deeply about these issues in the code from your question:

- **What is `Image`? Where does it come from? You've imported `http`, `fs`, and `Canvas`, so those things are obviously defined. However, `Image` hase not been defined anywhere and it is not a built-in.**

  As it turns out, `Image` is from the node-canvas module, which you've imported with `Canvas = require('canvas')`. This means that `Image` is available as `Canvas.Image`.

  It's important to understand that this is because of the imports you've setup. You could just have easily have done `abc = require('canvas')`, and then `Image` would be available as `abc.Image`.
- **What is `ctx`? Where is that coming from?**

  Again, this is another variable that just hasn't been defined anywhere. Unlike `Image`, it isn't available as `Canvas.ctx`. It's just a random variable name that doesn't correspond to anything at this point, so trying to call `drawImage` on it is going to throw an exception.
- **What about `canvas` (lowercase)? What is that?**

  You are using `canvas.toDataURL`, but there is no variable called `canvas` anywhere. What are you expecting this piece of code to do? Right now it's just going to throw an exception saying that canvas is undefined.

I'd recommend reading documentation more closely and looking more closely at any example code you copy into your own applications in the future.

---

Here is the fixed code, with some comments to explain my changes. I figured this out by taking a quick look at the documentation at https://github.com/learnboost/node-canvas.

```
var http = require('http'), fs = require('fs'), 
Canvas = require('canvas');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var img = new Canvas.Image; // Create a new Image
        img.src = data;

        // Initialiaze a new Canvas with the same dimensions
        // as the image, and get a 2D drawing context for it.
        var canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);

        res.write('<html><body>');
        res.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
        res.write('</body></html>');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

Comment: Thanks Rohan. I actually had forgotten about defining the ctx and canvas variables but never noticed as I didn't manage to get to those errors yet. 

That link you have given is where I have gotten the example from as its shown on that page the author has used **new Image** instead of **Canvas.Image**.

Comment: Yeah, lazy documentation there. Just using `Image` within the context of the node-canvas module's code itself would work, since it defines `Image = canvas.Image` in its source (lib/canvas.js). However, it won't work in your own code unless you make the same definition.

Comment: It's a pity, but that poor documentation is still there. How can we punch their ass to fix this?

Comment: I opened a pull request with the change: https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/pull/418

Comment: @RohanSingh, Don't we need to wait for `ImageObj.onload` ?

Comment: very generous post!

Answer (score 5):

node-canvas now has a helper function, `loadImage`, that returns a Promise resolving to a loaded `Image` object. This prevents having to mess around with `onload` handlers like in the accepted answer.

```js
const http = require('http'); 
const fs = require('fs');
const Canvas = require('canvas');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/image.jpg', async function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const img = await Canvas.loadImage(data);
        const canvas = new Canvas(img.width, img.height);
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 4, img.height / 4);

        res.write('<html><body>');
        res.write('<img src="' + canvas.toDataURL() + '" />');
        res.write('</body></html>');
        res.end();
    });

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```